# Simple programming language with a md5/sha1 hash command?

Tags: python, security, syntax, hash, programming-languages

I'm looking to create a simple brute-force password-cracker which will hash an input from stdin and compare the result to an existing hash (for my securities class).

I've never done any actual programming involving hashes, though, since it's mostly been conceptual/mathematical parts so far. **Is there a (relatively) easy-to-learn language which has a simple hash command?** A friend of mine recommended Python but I'm not sure if there's anything else out there I could pick up within a day or two. I know a bit of C, but hashing seems relatively complicated and needs additional libraries.

Also, any syntax help with an actual hash command would be appreciated. The program itself needs to be able to support odd hash methods, like hashing a value twice or using a set salt that doesn't change, and be able to take input from stdin (for use with programs like johntheripper).

Comment: In PHP you can just write `sha1($password)` or `md5($password)`. It's super easy to learn to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that you're only being asked to *use* the hash functions, and not to implement the hash yourself, [Python's hashlib module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/hashlib.html) has routines for md5 and sha1:

[Updated for Python 3, in which `hashlib` wants bytes, not strings:]

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> s = 'something to hash'
>>> sb = s.encode("utf8")
>>> hashlib.md5(sb)
<md5 HASH object @ 0x7f36f5ce3440>
>>> hashlib.md5(sb).hexdigest()
'6f4815fdf1f1fd3f36ac295bf39d26b4'
>>> hashlib.sha1(sb).hexdigest()
'72668bc961b0a78bfa1633f6141bcea69ca37468'
```

[Legacy Python 2 version:]

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> s = 'something to hash'
>>> hashlib.md5(s)
<md5 HASH object @ 0xb7714ca0>
>>> hashlib.md5(s).hexdigest()
'6f4815fdf1f1fd3f36ac295bf39d26b4'
>>> hashlib.sha1(s).hexdigest()
'72668bc961b0a78bfa1633f6141bcea69ca37468'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think python is a fine choice for something like this. It has the [hashlib module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/hashlib.html?highlight=hashlib#hashlib) to start with, and if you need more power, the [PyCrypto toolkit](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) is easy to use and supports plenty of cryptographic primitives, including hashing. If you already know some C, then maybe just using that with the [openssl libraries](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html) will be easier for you to pick up. In any case, it is usually worth the investment to learn a crypto library for your preferred language (especially for a crypto class), because eventually you will want to use something that you won't want to code by hand and be confident that it is implemented correctly.

As for syntax with an actual hash command, here is an example in python with PyCrypto for getting a SHA256 hash (using python 3.2):

```
import Crypto.Hash.SHA256

to_hash = "hello, how are you?"
sha256 = Crypto.Hash.SHA256.new()
sha256.update(to_hash.encode())
dgst = sha256.hexdigest()
print(dgst)
```

produces the output

```
5c1940d2a11cd8b1e256ea4183ba22cddfa7cc0d00610a159bd7f5886d01067a
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hashlib` library in python contains the following :

```
'md5', 'new', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512'
```

for details check:
http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/hashlib.html

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update(b"Nobody inspects")
>>> m.update(b" the spammish repetition")
>>> m.digest()
b'\xbbd\x9c\x83\xdd\x1e\xa5\xc9\xd9\xde\xc9\xa1\x8d\xf0\xff\xe9'
>>> m.digest_size
16
>>> m.block_size
64
```

Answer (score 0):

This small python program suits best for these type of small jobs

hash.py

```
import hashlib
import sys
try:
    hash_name = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print 'Specify the hash name as the first argument.'
else:
    try:
        data = sys.argv[2]
    except IndexError:
        print 'Please enter the data to be hashed'
        sys.exit()
    h = hashlib.new(hash_name)
    h.update(data)
    print h.hexdigest()
```

Output

```
$ python hash.py sha1 password1
e38ad214943daad1d64c102faec29de4afe9da3d
$ python hash.py sha256 password1
0b14d501a594442a01c6859541bcb3e8164d183d32937b851835442f69d5c94e
$ python hash.py md5 password1
7c6a180b36896a0a8c02787eeafb0e4c
```

Answer (score -1):

No programming language worth its salt can be learned in a few days. You may be able to get the syntax figured out, but not much beyond that. I like this article: http://norvig.com/21-days.html

There is probably not a best programming language for this. I can recommend C#, as it has simple cryptography classes in `System.Security.Cryptography`.

To find the MD5 hash of a byte array, you can use something like this:

```
byte[] hash = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(myByteArray);
```

To use SHA1, just replace MD5 with SHA1.

If you want to get the hash of an ASCII string, you can get a byte array like so:

```
byte[] myByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString);
```

An example function for converting a string to a hash:

```
// At the top of the file:
// using System.Security.Cryptography;
// using System.Text;

byte[] GetHash(string message)
{
    return MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
}
```

Comment: I completely disagree. You can learn python in less than a day - sure, you won't know the ins and outs, but a basic knowledge and enough to do this? Definitely.

Comment: *Any* programming language worth its salt (was that a pun?) can be learned in a few minutes if you already understand the principles of programming. The language *is* the syntax. Yes, there are cultural approaches to each language, but any programmer can use a language to a significant degree without really understanding its culture (e.g. the fairly unpythonic, but perfectly functional [avro API](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/avro) that I'm working with right now. (To learn to program is another story, and learning a language is only a small part of that.)

Comment: I know that it is easy to learn enough to 'make it work', with almost any language. However, you can hardly learn anything useful in one day. In my experience, the most significant part of a language is the libraries that are available. There are also many subtle differences between languages, that can trip up people who aren't careful. A language goes far, far beyond syntax.

Comment: Why would you recommend a language with a lot of tricky syntax to someone who specifically says that they need to pick up the language quickly?

Comment: @Marcin: I personally don't think C# is hard to learn. The basic syntax isn't tricky at all, and most of the other features are not necessary for a simple hashing program. I am drawing from experience, where I picked up C# by writing one (medium-small) project. I am not degrading python in any way. I agree that python is a good language for learning programming, but I prefer C#.

Comment: @KendallFrey I think it's fair to say that the syntactic ins-and-outs of any language with typed variables and substantial syntactic redundancy are more difficult to learn that a language which avoids those. This isn't even a question of a good language to learn programming - the OP also wants to be able to pick it up fast. If you think C# can't be learnt in a day, and you like it, while python users suggest the basics can be learnt in a day, that is a fairly compelling argument. (Of course, not as compelling as an actual study).

Comment: @Marcin: I realize that I am biased toward C#, and you are biased toward python, but IMO, typed variables are no problem, especially if you already know how to use them (see question). And what did you mean by 'substantial syntactic redundancy'? O?o

Comment: @KendallFrey Things like repeated type declarations, statement terminators, keywords like `new` to modify behaviour, etc. There's a lot of syntax to understand before one can write even minimal programmes. This is a feature of all C-derived languages (and many others, like pascal). There's a reason that almost no-one chooses such languages for scripting purposes.

Comment: @KendallFrey Please understand that this isn't a question of "what is the best language in general", but simply "what is a language that can be learned and understood very quickly". I would have suggested something like Standard ML over C# for this purpose, because it can be explained in total in a couple of pages.

Comment: @Marcin: I'm confused. What are repeated type declarations, and how does new 'modify behaviour'? You seem to be thinking of C or C++. Please do not think of C# as a C++ derivative. And every imperative programming language has statement terminators, python included.

Comment: @KendallFrey By repeated type declarations, I mean the fact that you have to declare the type of everything that is typed, individually. C# *is* derivative of C++. Python has *optional* statement terminators (javascript is another example of a language with optional terminators). In any case, you have not made any positive case to defend your position that C# is as easy to learn to as python, or any "dynamic" language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9596/discussion-between-kendall-frey-and-marcin)